# Link to image from pdf

Tags: image, pdf, href

My app dynamically generates a pdf file which is self-contained. inside the pdf, amongst other content, are images displayed in smaller dimensions than the original image.

The user can see the original image by clicking on the small image which is wrapped in an `<a>` tag and has href to data url with the binary (base64) of the original image.

My problem is that this approach is blocked for security reasons by almost all pdf viewers (blocking navigation to data url).

I could host the original images on a server and link to them, but this approach does not suite me because:

a. I want the pdf to be self contained and work even offline.
b. I don't wish to maintain such a server.
c. The images are manipulated dynamically before the pdf is created, and this would create some headaches with synchronization of the images with the server.

I am generating the pdf by printing an html through puppeteer. I could use pdf file attachments and internal references, but this approach allows the functionality only if the pdf is opened in acrobat reader (and not in e.g. Google Chrome). I am willing to change the method of pdf generation if this could provide a solution to my problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community the html has <a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,...">image link</a> and is printed to pdf with puppeteer.